# Convert Kendo grid to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-grid, stringify

I have a Kendo Grid displayed on a site. I want to be able to convert this grid to HTML in some way and post to the server, so that I can construct an email that can be sent with that HTML.

1. What is the best way to do that? I tried `$(#gridname).html()`, but that includes a whole bunch of JS and relative references to CSS that won't work in email.
2. I tried converting the grid to JSON and passing that to the server using `JSON.stringify($("#gridname").data().kendoGrid._data)`, so that I can construct a simple table there at the server, but that only includes the "data" and no information about he headers.

I can try to manually construct the data by looping through the table, but I am hoping there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324565/how-to-get-the-displayed-data-of-kendogrid-in-json-format

Comment: I think he was the formatted grid, not just the data

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Also, not just the data, but the column headers as well.