# Attempting to read the full datasource from a grid is only returning the view?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code:

```
function foo()
{
    var view = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view();
    var data = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

    var b = (view == ds);
}
```

My grid has 6,527 records, with 10 records per page. Both my `view` and `data` objects only have 10 elements.

In this scenario, `b` is `true`.

According to:

- [This post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2004374.aspx?How+Can+I+Get+All+Rows+In+Kendo+Grid+In+All+Pages), my second line is supposed to return all rows from all pages
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362977/1189566) implies the same thing -- that `dataSource.data()` would return all of the data
- [From Telerik's forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/all-items-in-a-grid#3DlYCczKI0Sp5LpucyRMhQ) again it looks like `data()` should be what I want

So, how can I get **all** rows of data from my grid, even if they aren't currently visible?

Answer (score 2):

To get all the data items, you need to disable server-side data operations in the dataSource settings. Note that this will make the DataSource instance request all items at once, which will slow down initial data binding.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverPaging

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/overview#mixed-data-operations-mode